# How to force a row and its cols use 100% of the height of its parent element (jumbotron)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image: This is what I have and what I want]

So I want to vertical and horizontal align the slogan to the jumbotron, the top logo is in it correct place and the small isotype should go all the way on the base of the jumbotron.

any help is greatly appreciated.

```css
#hero {
    height: 50vh;
    background-image: url("/img/background.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="hero">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 text-left align-top h-25">
                    <img src="/img/toplogo.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 text-center align-middle h-auto">
                    <img src="img/slogan.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 text-right align-bottom test">
                    <img src="/img/logowhite.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use `100vh` instead of `50vh` if you want it full height?

Comment: @ZimSystem I mean the row should take 100% of the jumbotron

Comment: Then use `h-100` on the container and row https://www.codeply.com/go/dcghjKAxRI

Comment: yes, that did it!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct, you asking for align the slogan vertically to the center and align the isotype to the bottom as you showed in above image. You can add below inline style parts to the slogan and small isotype.

To align slogan to mid:

```
<img src="img/slogan.png" alt="" style="top:--height from the top-- ;">
```

or

```
<img src="img/slogan.png" alt="" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;">
```

To set small isotype into bottom:

```
<img src="/img/logowhite.png" alt="" style="top:--height from the top-- ;">
```

or

```
<img src="img/logowhite.png" alt="" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;">
```

I think, this will works on you.

Answer (score 0):

As user @ZimSystem said it was just a matter of adding h-100 to the row and container

Thanks for your help.